# CodeDomProvider: where is the LIB environment variable located?

Tags: c#, .net, csc

I'm using a `System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp")` to compile C# classes on the fly. Recently I've switched from Visual Studio 2010 to Vistual Studio 2012. I also uninstalled SQL 2005. Since these events I've been unable to compile my classes due to the following error:

> Invalid search path 'C:\Program Files\SQLXML 4.0\bin\' specified in
>   'LIB environment variable' -- 'The system cannot find the path
>   specified.

**Where is this "LIB environment variable" located?**

<sub>I've checked my Windows 7 Environment Variables (Control Panel\System\Advanced system settings\Advanced\Environment Variables\System variable), but it's not there.</sub>

Comment: As a workaround I've created the directory 'C:\Program Files\SQLXML 4.0\bin\' I still can't find this amazing LIB variable :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating the directory will fix the problem.