# Invalid search path 'C:\Program Files\SQLXML 4.0\bin\' specified in 'LIB environment variable' -- 'The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, environment-variables, sqlxml

**Problem**: Building Winform C# control library started throwing this error for no apparent reason.

**Error**:

> Invalid search path 'C:\Program Files\SQLXML 4.0\bin\' specified in
>   'LIB environment variable' -- 'The system cannot find the path
>   specified.

Oddly enough, I got this error while editing my Winform C# control project for no apparent reason.

*Facts*

- I haven't changed any references or project settings in any way
- Did just recover from a strange issue with SQL server dying on my machine requirement me to uninstall some older versions (like SQL2005, 2012, etc) and reinstall 2014. This seems a likely cause
- Article [about LIB enironment varible here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f4302854-e13b-408b-98b0-41e820a7312f/invalid-search-path-in-lib-environment-variable-warning-cs1668?forum=csharpide) didn't help... I have no LIB variable defined.
- Path variable had no such reference
- Searching my csproj file revealed no clues.  My only reference to anything XML is just System.XML

**Hypothesis**

I suspect something on my machine is referencing this but just cannot find it.  Please see my work around below if you don't care why and just want to get it working. However, if you know the underlying problem and have a suggestion please post it.

Answer (score 0):

**Fix/Workaround**
For me, this old article [to just create the directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395098/codedomprovider-where-is-the-lib-environment-variable-located) fixed my issue.